# Subclipse SVN Content Filtering While a Commit is done

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, tortoisesvn, subclipse

I have set up subclipse for SVN on eclipse. Sometimes, we forget to remove `console.logs()` in the `JavaScript` source files and these are causing some errors on `IE`

So I was thinking if there could be an alert message that can be shown if subclipse detects any `console.logs()` during SVN Commit or it would be better if it could completely erase those `console.logs()` all together!(I Know I'm Asking For More Here!).

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to perform a check at the server via a `pre-commit` hook script. Inspect the content coming in; if any JS file contains uncommented `console.logs()` statements (or any instances of `console.logs()`, period), reject the commit & inform the user why.

You may have to maintain a working copy on the server to apply the diffs to, to perform this check properly.

If you try to do any checking at the client end, you will have to configure each client separately *and* trust that users only use the client that you've configured. Assuming you have any SVN clients that offer this functionality (I'm only aware of TortoiseSVN allowing for anything remotely like this).

Your Subversion client and server should *never* automatically "purge" lines as you suggest in that last paragraph. You'll inevitably lose content you don't want to lose, and break your builds.

Answer (score -2):

You can use svn:ignore to ignore the JavaScript or Logs directory. Here is an article from IBM for how to use Subversion with Eclipse. You can go see the "Ignoring files" section. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecl-subversion/

> If your project generates files, or otherwise includes files that you
>   don't want to check in to the Subversion repository, you can tell
>   Subclipse to ignore them. Right-click the file or directory you want
>   to exclude from version control, then choose Team > Add to svn:ignore
>   to display the Add to svn:ignore dialog.

Comment: He's not asking to ignore JavaScript or logfiles altogether - he wants to be alerted if any of his source files contain specific content.

Comment: @alroc Why downvote? What's wrong with my suggestion. He doesn't want to check in those files(Look at his question, he even want to erase  those logs). So He can just svn:ignore them. Isn't that a lot easier, and standard way to do it.

Comment: He's not asking to delete the logs - he's asking to delete the log *statements* that are contained **within the source code** that he wants to otherwise keep.